# Where do I make the change to increase the stack size to 2MB?

Tags: iis

I want to modify the stack size in IIS to 2MB as per the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/advanced?view=aspnetcore-7.0#modify-the-stack-size

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet"
    arguments=".\MyApp.dll"
    stdoutLogEnabled="false"
    stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout"
    hostingModel="inprocess">
  <handlerSettings>
    <handlerSetting name="stackSize" value="2097152" />
  </handlerSettings>
</aspNetCore>
```

What is not mentioned here is where do I make this change? Is it in an IIS file or in the .NET project file?

Answer (score 0):

"Configure the managed stack size using the stackSize setting in bytes in the *web.config* file."

The web.config of your application. Global settings are in applicationhost.config.